# Input boxes of Bootstrap are not responsive and cannot change their width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a newbie to bootstrap and am currently working on a simple page. So far, I completed following code, but I have a few problems. First issue is the width of input boxes, I need them to be a bit wider but could not make it. They are also not responsive. Another issue is with the logo, it is always on the left of the banner but when the window width is too small it goes to the right of the window rather than left of the banner.

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.form-control {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5;
    -moz-border-radius: 5;
    border-radius: 5;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


    <div id="header" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" style="background-color: green;">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div id="logo" style="margin-right: 0px; float: right;">
                    <img
                        src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA"
                        width="40px" height="40px" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div id="banner">
                    <img
                        src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-32Ge8DaAq_81IBLPFdRWmKVYgvN9YyDKKjXh6CTTpgey8qbC"
                        height="40px;" width="300px;" />
                </div>
                <fieldset>
                    <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post"
                        action="employee/search.htm" name="employeeForm" id="employeeForm">
                        <div class="form">
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text"
                                    name="firstName" id="fistName" placeholder="First Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="lastName"
                                    id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Click1</a> <a href="#"
                                class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Click2</a>
                    </form>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div id="images" style="float: left;">
                    <img
                        src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA"
                        width="20px" height="20px" /> <img
                        src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA"
                        width="20px" height="20px" /> <img
                        src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA"
                        width="20px" height="20px" /> <img
                        src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_FCNfsR_UhKGdOTtUKK8XfQXKnlgw5Q0jaBbdiCSBTnCoaGgqIA"
                        width="20px" height="20px" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="container">...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input fields: On the [bootstrap page](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) there's a big warning box, that inline fields may require custom widths. So you have to handle the width by yourself.

Logo: The logo is always on the right sight of the related container because of the `float: right;` you've applied. On desktop mode it looks like it's on the left because it's in a floating column. On mobile mode there's no column floating anymore. You could set the logo floating via CSS using a media query so you can handle the right/non-floating behavior.